# Errors with Library in Azure Web App (Net Core on Linux)

Tags: .net, linux, azure

I am developing a web app using .Net Core and Microsoft Azure as hosting.

Today I added this piece of code that on my PC works perfectly:

```
        try {
            using (var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(postedFile.OpenReadStream())) { }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.LogError(e.ToString());

            return false;
        } finally {
            postedFile.OpenReadStream().Position = 0;
        }
```

But on Azure, it gives this exception (saw thanks to Logger.LogError):

```
        System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception.
    ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libgdiplus' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibgdiplus: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
      at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdiplusStartup(IntPtr& token, StartupInput& input, StartupOutput& output)
      at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip..cctor()
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
      at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipLoadImageFromDelegate_linux(StreamGetHeaderDelegate getHeader, StreamGetBytesDelegate getBytes, StreamPutBytesDelegate putBytes, StreamSeekDelegate doSeek, StreamCloseDelegate close, StreamSizeDelegate size, IntPtr& image)
     at System.Drawing.Image.InitializeFromStream(Stream stream)
      at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Stream stream)
      at PushMeWebServer.Utils.FileUploadCheckHelper.IsImage(IFormFile postedFile) in D:\Downloads\WorkspaceVisualStudio\PushMe_code\PushMeWebServer\PushMe\Utils\FileUploadCheckHelper.cs:line 71
```

I tried to install, using SSH, some missing libraries like libc6-dev libgdiplus libx11-dev but I didn't resolve it. Why? It's my first experience with this environment so I am not an expert

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the .NET Core application as a standalone console app, or are you running it with the [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows)? I suspect this is due to the [sandbox limitations](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) of Azure's App Service:

> For the sake of radical attack surface area reduction, the sandbox prevents almost all of the Win32k.sys APIs from being called, which practically means that most of User32/GDI32 system calls are blocked. For most applications this is not an issue since most Azure Web Apps do not require access to Windows UI functionality (they are web applications after all).